# jQuery plugin only seems to work in safari / FF but not IE 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have code located here

http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/5XAUb/

This works in Safari / FF (for the most part, a small bug with the fadeIn on FF) but doesn't work on IE. It has to do with the lines that use `$(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ').splice(-1).toString();`.

Basically it is not able to get the elementType in IE7 or IE8 (haven't tested IE9) but works in FF and Safari just fine.

Does anyone know why IE doesn't seem to like this jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IE` and `Opera` require the second argument for `splice`, which is proper for `splice`.

**[Splice Usage Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much. Didn't know IE required a second parameter for the splice! I updated the splice to `splice(-1,1)` and it now works properly on all browsers!